# eBay SOAP API 'Invalid postage type' ErrorCode 10080 when sending invoice

Tags: soap, ebay-api

I am trying to send automatic ebay invoice adding the freight amount but I get the error code 10080 while doing it.

**My Code**

```
$ShippingServiceOptions = new stdClass();
$ShippingServiceOptions->ShippingService="AU_Frieght";
//$ShippingServiceOptions->ShippingType="AU_Frieght";
$ShippingServiceOptions->ShippingServiceCost = array('_'=>99,'currencyID'=>'AUD');
$ShippingServiceOptions->ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = array('_'=>0,'currencyID'=>'AUD');
$ShippingServiceOptions->ShippingInsuranceCost = array('_'=>0,'currencyID'=>'AUD');

$ShippingServiceOptions->InsuranceFee=0.00;
$ShippingServiceOptions->ShippingServicePriority=1;


$invoiceRequest = new stdClass();
$invoiceRequest->Version = 803;
$invoiceRequest->OrderID = "200937602540-950490227010";
$invoiceRequest->TransactionID=950490227010;
$invoiceRequest->ItemID     = 200937602540; 
$invoiceRequest->ShippingServiceOptions = $ShippingServiceOptions;

$sendInvoice = new EbayAPI();
$result=$sendInvoice->SendInvoice($invoiceRequest);
var_dump($result);
```

**Error**

```
object(stdClass)[393]
  public 'Timestamp' => string '2013-10-24T02:35:47.049Z' (length=24)
  public 'Ack' => string 'Failure' (length=7)
  public 'Errors' => 
    object(stdClass)[394]
      public 'ShortMessage' => string 'Invalid postage type.' (length=21)
      public 'LongMessage' => string 'Invalid <ShippingType>.' (length=23)
      public 'ErrorCode' => string '10080' (length=5)
      public 'SeverityCode' => string 'Error' (length=5)
      public 'ErrorClassification' => string 'RequestError' (length=12)
  public 'Version' => string '843' (length=3)
  public 'Build' => string 'E843_INTL_APIXO_16449518_R1' (length=27)
```

Thanks
Abnab

Answer (score 0):

AU_Freight can not be specified as the ValidForSellingFlow flag for the service is not set when calling GeteBayDetails. eBay will only allow services where this flag is true. More information is avaliable in the official [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails.ValidForSellingFlow).

Shown below is the current list of shipping services that can be passed in the *ShippingService* field. Since these values can change as eBay add and remove services you should call [GeteBayDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html) periodically.

(Note the value to specify is shown in bold)

## **Domestic Shipping Services**

**Standard Services**

- **AU_StandardDelivery** Standard delivery (1-6 business days)
- **AU_Regular** Australia Post Parcel Post Parcel (1-6 business days)
- **AU_RegularParcelWithTracking** Australia Post Regular Parcel + Tracking (1-6 business days)
- **AU_RegularParcelWithTrackingAndSignature** Australia Post Parcel Post Parcel + Signature (1-6 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidParcelPostSatchels500g** Australia Post Prepaid Parcel Post 500g Satchel (1-6 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidParcelPostSatchels3kg** Australia Post Prepaid Parcel Post 3kg Satchel (1-6 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidParcelPostSatchels5kg** Australia Post Prepaid Parcel Post 5kg Satchel (1-6 business days)
- **AU_Registered** Australia Post Regular Parcel Registered (1-6 business days)
- **AU_RegisteredParcelPostPrepaidSatchel500g** Australia Post Prepaid Parcel Post 500g Satchel + Signature (1-6 business days)
- **AU_RegisteredParcelPostPrepaidSatchel3kg** Australia Post Prepaid Parcel Post 3kg Satchel + Signature (1-6 business days)
- **AU_RegisteredParcelPostPrepaidSatchel5kg** Australia Post Prepaid Parcel Post 5kg Satchel + Signature (1-6 business days)
- **AU_RegisteredParcelPost** Australia Post Regular Parcel Registered (1-6 business days)

**Express Services**

- **AU_ExpressDelivery** Express delivery (1-3 business days)
- **AU_Express**    Australia Post Express Post Parcel (1-3 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostSatchel500g** Australia Post Express Post 500g Satchel (1-3 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostSatchel3kg** Australia Post Express Post 3kg Satchel (1-3 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostSatchel5kg** Australia Post Express Post 5kg Satchel (1-3 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostPlatinum500g** Australia Post Express Post 500g Satchel + Signature (1-3 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostPlatinum3kg** Australia Post Express Post 3kg Satchel + Signature (1-3 business days)
- **AU_DHL** DHL (1-3 business days)
- **AU_FastwayCouriers** Fastway Couriers (1-3 business days)
- **AU_StarTrackExpress** Star Track Express (1-3 business days)
- **AU_TNT** TNT (1-3 business days)
- **AU_Toll** Toll Consumer Delivery (1-3 business days)

**Services from outside Australia**

- **AU_EconomyDeliveryFromOutsideAU** Economy delivery from outside AU (11-20 business days)
- **AU_StandardDeliveryFromOutsideAU** Standard delivery from outside AU (6-10 business days)
- **AU_ExpeditedDeliveryFromOutsideAU** Expedited delivery from outside AU (1-5 business days)
- **AU_TntIntlExp** TNT International Express (2-4 business days)

## **International Shipping Services**

- **AU_StandardInternational** Standard International Flat Rate Postage (3-15 business days)
- **AU_AirMailInternational** AusPost Air Mail Parcel (3-10 business days)
- **AU_AusPostRegisteredPostInternationalParcel** AusPost Registered Post International Parcel (3-10 business days)
- **AU_AusPostRegisteredPostInternationalPaddedBag500g** AusPost Registered Post International Padded Bag 500g (3-10 business days)
- **AU_AusPostRegisteredPostInternationalPaddedBag1kg** AusPost Registered Post International Padded Bag 1kg (3-10 business days)
- **AU_SeaMailInternational** AusPost Sea Mail Parcel (30-60 business days)
- **AU_ExpeditedInternational** Express International Flat Rate Postage (3-7 business days)
- **AU_ExpressPostInternational** AusPost Express Post International Parcel (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalEnvelopeC5** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Envelope C5 (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalEnvelopeB4** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Envelope B4 (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalSatchels2kg** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Satchel 2Kg (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalSatchels3kg** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Satchel 3Kg (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalBox5kg** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Box 5Kg (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalBox10kg** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Box 10Kg (3-7 business days)
- **AU_PrePaidExpressPostInternationalBox20kg** AusPost PrePaid Express Post International Box 20Kg (3-7 business days)
- **AU_ExpressCourierInternational** AusPost Express Courier International (2-4 business days)

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks I that out and its not showing that issue now. But it is showing error "You can't offer both Domestic and International postage services together."  I have only used ShippingServiceOptions only.

Comment: I've looked into the issue some more and found that it's due to the fact that ValidForSellingFlow is not set for AU_Freight. If you specify one of the other shipping services the invoice should be sent.